# Use live connection in power BI but also be able to edit data and create columns/tables

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, powerquery

I have been trying to edit data in power BI or power query with a live connection to a SQL server analysis service database. When I connect to the server, I don't see a data table, and I can't add columns or tables, only create new measures. I want to be able to edit the data and create new columns with conditions. I have found a way to do this in Excel by connecting to SQL server analysis service database and then using the Excel file in power BI (creating new columns in power query first), but I want the connection to be live and update when new data comes in, which I don't think it does. Does anyone know a workaround? I want to be able to use a live connection and add custom/conditional columns in power BI/power query. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Assuming by 'live connection' that you mean that you are utilizing Direct Query mode to access your data?

Comment: Live Connection on cubes doesn't allow changes, you need to have some sort of composite model https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/directquery-for-power-bi-datasets-and-azure-analysis-services-preview/ This may help but you cube version may not support it